# C# changing process FileName while running

Tags: c#, hyperlink, process, youtube

I am adding a feature to my Twitch bot that I am developing where it will automatically open a youtube video when a new video comes up in the queue. I am having a problem trying to switch the created process filename from process.StartInfo.FileName = youtubeLink1 to youtubeLink2. It says that the process has already exited when I try to kill it and restart it. Is there anyway to easily switch this whenever? Please don't recommend WebBrowser controls because I have already tried that. Due to the copyright on music videos, they will not play in the WebBrowser control (unless you know a way around this). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not really closing the process or waiting for its exit event before trying to change its `StartInfo` properties, and this cannot be done.

Try using `WaitForExit()` and `Close()` like the code below:

```
Process _process = new Process();
_process.StartInfo.FileName = "youtubeLink1.exe";
_process.Start();
_process.WaitForExit();

// Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
_process.CloseMainWindow();

// Free resources associated with process.
_process.Close();

// Now you can change the name
_process.StartInfo.FileName = "youtubeLink2.exe";
...
```

Comment: I pretty much already have this code other than the CloseMainWindow(). I added that, but it still does not work. Here is the error I get:

System.InvalidOperationException: Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.

Comment: Fails on CloseMainWindow() or Close() if I don't use the first one.

Comment: What do you mean *if I don't use the first one* ?